# Powershell function to generate samAccountName

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Im trying to write PS function which is taking `FirstName` and `LastName` as parameters and returns `samaccountname`. Here is the algorithm how the function should work.

> Name: Richard Testing

Now look if login `richard` is taken. If `richard` is taken try `richard.t`. If `richard.t` is taken try `richard.te`. If `richard.te` is taken try `richard.tes`, and so on.

Below is my code. I think this can be done in a much easier way than with if loops.

```
$FirstName = "Richard"
$LastName = "Testing"

function Remove-StringLatinCharacters {
    Param([string]$String)
    [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes($String))
}

$FirstnameToUPN = (Remove-StringLatinCharacters -String $firstname).ToLower()
$LastnamenameToUPN = (Remove-StringLatinCharacters -String $lastname).ToLower()

$user = $(try {Get-ADUser $FirstnameToUPN} catch {$null})
if ($user -ne $null) {
    $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]
    $user = $(try {Get-ADUser $upn} catch {$null})
    if ($user -ne $null) {
        $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]
        $user = $(try {Get-ADUser $upn} catch {$null})
        if ($user -ne $null) {
            $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]+$LastnamenameToUPN[2]
            $user = $(try {Get-ADUser $upn} catch {$null})
            if ($user -ne $null) {
                $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]+$LastnamenameToUPN[2]+$LastnamenameToUPN[3]
            } else {
                $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]+$LastnamenameToUPN[2]+$LastnamenameToUPN[3]
            }
        } else {
            $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]
        }
    } else {
        $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]
    }
} else {
    $upn=$FirstnameToUPN
}
```

---

**Edit #1:**

```
$upn = $FirstnameToUPN
if (Get-Aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $upn}) {
    $upn = $FirstnameToUPN+"."+$LastnamenameToUPN[0]
    if (Get-Aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $upn}) {
        $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]
        if (Get-Aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $upn}) {
            $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]+$LastnamenameToUPN[2]
            if (Get-Aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $upn}) {
                $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]+$LastnamenameToUPN[2]+$LastnamenameToUPN[3]
                if (Get-Aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $upn}) {
                    $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]+$LastnamenameToUPN[2]+$LastnamenameToUPN[3]+$LastnamenameToUPN[4]
                    if (Get-Aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $upn}) {
                        $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]+$LastnamenameToUPN[2]+$LastnamenameToUPN[3]+$LastnamenameToUPN[4]+$LastnamenameToUPN[5]
                    } else {
                        $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]+$LastnamenameToUPN[2]+$LastnamenameToUPN[3]+$LastnamenameToUPN[4]
                    }
                } else {
                    $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]+$LastnamenameToUPN[2]+$LastnamenameToUPN[3]
                }
            } else {
                $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]+$LastnamenameToUPN[2]+$LastnamenameToUPN[3]
            }
        } else {
            $upn = $FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN[0]+$LastnamenameToUPN[1]
        }
    } else {
        $upn = $FirstnameToUPN+"."+$LastnamenameToUPN[0]
    }
} else {
    $upn = $FirstnameToUPN
}
```

Comment: A little hint on the side: Instead of trying to catch the error everytime when using `get-aduser $upn`, you can just set a correct Filter: `Get-Aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $upn}`. This will result in `$null` if the user doesn't exist without throwing errors around.

Comment: Even better would be to just try and create the user and catch the error if it fails on "already exists". You can then throw that in a loop, with a counter to continually go up using the next letter in the surname until it successfully creates the user.

Comment: @Paxz thank you for this. Seems to working great. Im curious If there would be easy way to create a loop for finding login as Ross Lyons said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with just the first name, then append characters from the last name until the resulting account name does not exists in AD or you run out of characters:

```
$acct = $FirstnameToUPN
$cnt  = 1
while (-not (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$acct'") -and $cnt -le $LastnameToUPN.Length) {
    $acct = "${FirstnameToUPN}." + $LastnameToUPN.Substring(0, $cnt)
    $cnt++
}

if (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$acct'") {
    Write-Error "No unused account name found for ${firstname} ${lastname}."
}
```

Comment: Ofc you have to post the exact same answer I had in mind 3 seconds before I hit post.. Take my upvote god damn it...

Comment: *\*blows smoke from muzzle\**

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking each possible username individually until you find a match, you can compare *all* the existing username matches to *all* the possible new username combinations.

This actually completes the whole operation with only a single call to `Get-ADUser`:

```
# get existing accounts that could match using wildcard '$FirstnameToUPN*'
$existingAccounts = Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -like '$FirstnameToUPN*'" -properties samAccountName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname

# create all possible samaccountname combinations
$all_samaccountname = 0..($LastnamenameToUPN.Length) | % {$FirstnameToUPN + "." + $LastnamenameToUPN.substring(0, $_)}

# change first entry from "Firstname." to just "Firstname"
$all_samaccountname.Item(0) = $all_samaccountname.Item(0).TrimEnd('.')

# remove existing accounts from the possible samaccountname combinations
# then select the first available samaccountname match
$upn = $all_samaccountname | Where-Object { $existingAccounts -notcontains $_ } | Select-Object -First 1

# error if there's no matches and no username combination available
if (!($upn)) {
    Write-Error "No possible upn combinations available for: $firstname $lastname"
}
```