# Function to generate samaccountname in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a PS function that can generate ***SamAccountName*** in a specific way, I have found another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646395/powershell-function-to-generate-samaccountname) but it is not similar to what i'm trying to do.
I need the ***SamAccountName*** to be generated like this:

`UNIT + initial_of_firstName + initial_of_lastName`

for example employee ***Jane Doe*** in unit ***FLN*** could have ***FLNjd*** as ***SamAccountName***, and the function should check if that `ID` is taken by another user and if true then ***SamAccountName*** should be:

`UNIT + initial_of_firstName + first_two_initials_of_lastName` such as ***FLNjdo***

and if that is also taken then ***SamAccountName*** should be:

`UNIT + first_two_initials_of_firstName + first_two_initials_of_lastName` such as ***FLNjado***

and if that is also taken then ***SamAccountName*** should be:

`UNIT + first_two_initials_of_firstName + first_two_initials_of_lastName + 1` such as ***FLNjado1***

and from here it starts adding numbers `2, 3, 4....` as long as the function finds that the `ID` exists.

I only managed to extract the initials needed:

```
$first_of_fname = ($_.Fname).Substring(0,1).ToLower() 

$first_of_lname = ($_.Lname).Substring(0,1).ToLower() 

$FirstandSecond_of_fname = ($_.Fname).Substring(0,2).ToLower() 

$FirstandSecond_of_lname = ($_.Lname).Substring(0,2).ToLower()
```

I need now to know how to generate the the ***SamAccountName*** in the above form and order.

ANy help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: you already have the logic.. unfortunately you wil need to do something simliar to what the other person did. lots of if else statements to continue generating until you hit numbers at the end. Then you can probably look up used number + 1

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
Function Get-SamAccountName {

    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        $Unit,  
        [Parameter(Position=1,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        $First,
        [Parameter(Position=2,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        $Last
    )

    $fcount = 1
    $lcount = 1
    $inc = 1
    $Sam = "{0}{1}{2}" -f $unit,$first.substring(0,$fcount).ToLower(),$last.substring(0,$lcount++).ToLower()
    while (Get-AdUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$Sam'") {
        if ($fcount -le 2) {
            $Sam = "{0}{1}{2}" -f $unit,$first.substring(0,$fcount++).ToLower(),$last.substring(0,$lcount).ToLower()
        } else {
            $Sam = "{0}{1}{2}{3}" -f $unit,$first.substring(0,2).ToLower(),$last.substring(0,2).ToLower(),$inc++
        }
    }
    $Sam
}
```

---

**Usage Option 1: Using Named Parameters**

```
Get-SamAccountName -Unit 'FLN' -First 'Sam' -Last 'Wise'
```

---

**Usage Option 2: Using positional parameters (unnamed)**

```
Get-SamAccountName 'FLN' 'Sam' 'Wise'
```

---

**Usage Option 3: Having A Text List Of Units and Names**

```
$users = Get-Content users.txt
$users

FLN,Sam,Wise
HRS,John,Doe
COM,Jane,Doe

$users | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Unit','First','Last' | Foreach {
    $_ | Get-SamAccountName
}
```

The pipe to `ConvertFrom-Csv` can be skipped here if your file is already a CSV with the proper headers.

---

**Explanation:**

The function returns a string that represents an available `SamAccountName` value.

`$fcount` is the first name character count that we want to retrieve. `$lcount` is the last name character count that we want to retrieve. `$inc` is the number we want to append to the username if needed.

`$var++` notation increments the `$var` value by one ***after*** its line is executed. The timing of `$fcount++` and `$lcount++` allows us to retrieve (1,1),(1,2),(2,2) characters from (first,last) while minimizing code. `$inc++` will increment after the current `$inc` value is retrieved.

`-f` is the string [format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html).

The `while` loop will only execute if the current created `SamAccountName` value is found.

**Note:** The code shortening complexity may or may not be worth it. It does not gain much from a performance perspective, but I do feel code complexity on this level is merely relative.

Comment: AdminOfThings, I will test it and let You know, thank You.

Answer (score 0):

To take a different approach, instead of multiple if statements, you can use the `switch` statement "backwards" to find out what is `$null` or not available, and fall back to the default switch which is the final `while` iteration loop incrementing the count.

```
#Get substrings
$first_of_fname = ($_.Fname).Substring(0,1).ToLower() 
$first_of_lname = ($_.Lname).Substring(0,1).ToLower() 
$FirstandSecond_of_fname = ($_.Fname).Substring(0,2).ToLower() 
$FirstandSecond_of_lname = ($_.Lname).Substring(0,2).ToLower() 

#create patters to match on
$pattern1 = $UNIT + $first_of_fname + $first_of_lname
$pattern2 = $UNIT + $first_of_fname + $FirstandSecond_of_lname
$pattern3 = $UNIT + $FirstandSecond_of_fname + $FirstandSecond_of_lname

#evaluate what is available
switch($null){
    (Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -like '$pattern1'"){
        Write-Host "$pattern1 - Free"
        break
    }
    (Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -like '$pattern2'"){
        Write-Host "$pattern2 - Free"
        break
    }
    (Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -like '$pattern3'"){
        Write-Host "$pattern3 - Free"
        break
    }
    default {
        $cnt  = 1
        while (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$pattern3$cnt'") {
            $cnt++
        }
        Write-Host "$pattern3$cnt - Free"
        break
    }
}
```